# .htaccess RewriteCond filter on name position

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would appreciate help on how to filter a rediction that in fact works too well !

This line in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule babar/(.*)$ index.php?origin=babar&request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

perfectly does the job when trying to access http://mydomain.com/babar/whatever

But when trying to access : http:/mydomain.com/whatever/babar, the RewriteRule still has effect which I don't want to. I only want the rediction occurs when "babar" is the first parameter after my domain name.

I know I have to add a RewriteCond (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) but unfortunatly can't understand what to write to make this test effective !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must use line start anchor as well in your regex:**

```
RewriteRule ^babar/(.*)$ index.php?origin=babar&request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```